# How to update millions of documents independently? PHP + Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a very big aggregate which sums up some activity for every user (inside a collection).
This aggregate returns millions of results (each user activity). with this format:

```
 Array ( [_id] => Array ( [user] =>
      MongoId Object ( [$id] => 52050d48e654f6342c002d42 )
        [send] => 1
        [open] => 1
        [click] => 2 )
```

Now I need to do a few things:

- Update users with these results (increase existing values)
- After update compute an average for each user (opens / send)
- compare each average with a number and based on the result add a flag to the user?

How would be a good approach to update users with these results from the aggregation without looping through them and updating each at a time?

Comment: @verbumSapienti link you provided is completely unrelated, did you read question?

Comment: No, that's used for mongo indexing :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the example result you shared:

```
{
  user: ObjectId("52050d48e654f6342c002d42"),
  send: 1,
  open: 1,
  click: 2
}
```

...will need to do the following:

- Increment the `send` and `open` fields for that user by `1`, each.
- Compare the post-increment `open`/`send` ratio (not stored) with some value, and set a boolean flag on the user document based on the result of that comparison.

At best, I think you could pre-aggregate users that would receive similar updates and issue [multi-document updates](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-multiple-documents) where the `_id` is [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) in array of values; however, this still requires MongoDB to query for each user individually. There is a limit to the size of the `$in` array argument, but the main benefit of this strategy is that you'll send less operations between the driver and server, and you will receive a single GLE (i.e. get last error) response.

The `open`/`send` ratio calculation is going to prove more tricky, as that will require fetching those fields from all documents. After the update step, you may be able to issue a second aggregation against the user collection, and use [`$divide`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/#arithmetic-operators) on both fields to compute that value. You can then use the quotient and your other value in a [comparison operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/#comparison-operators). This would let your craft an aggregation result that contains only user IDs and a boolean value. From there, you would still need to issue more update statements from the driver, although grouping those into multi-document updates would be much simpler since there are only two possible values for the flag field.

I would definitely suggest making the flag field an always-present boolean, as that will let you change its value without worrying about creating a new field and inadvertently requiring the document to be moved on disk if it exceeds its allocated space. You should aim for [in-place updates](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/248614779/fast-updates-with-mongodb-update-in-place) whenever possible.

Lastly, one other option to look into with the PHP driver is the [write concern](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php) for your update operations. You may gain some performance (at the expense of error checking) by using a write concern of zero, as that will allow you to send updates to MongoDB as fast as possible, without waiting for error responses.